# How to make a bold button for an editable div in react.js

Tags: reactjs, contenteditable, execcommand

I would like to make an editor from scratch with a contenteditable div in react.js
The div is editable, but how can I add a button to make selected text bold?
I tried "document.execCommand('bold', false, null);", but cant make it work.

```
import React from 'react';

const Editor = () => {
    return (
        <div className="editor">
            <div className="toolbar">
                <button onclick={(e) => {
                    document.execCommand('bold', false, null);
                    e.preventDefault();
                }}>b</button>
            </div>
            <div className="editor-content" contenteditable>
                <h1>Test</h1>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div >
    )
}

export default Editor;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Props are case-sensitive. Refactor `onclick` to `onClick` and `contenteditable` to `contentEditable` and this implementation should work